# как сделать чтобы при нажатии появлялся контур, менялся фон или сам цвет, на React или это можно сделать в самом css?

Tags: css, reactjs, вёрстка

[image: нужно чтобы при нажатии менялся цвет]

[[image: тоже но цвет фона][2]]

[image: цвет фон]

как сделать чтобы при нажатии появлялся контур, менялся фон или сам цвет, на React,
как на вышеприкрепленных картинках

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Что из себя представляют картинки? В целом, можно делать по разному, все зависит от того, что должно происходить далее.

Comment: все зависит от конкретной разметки. По клику просто вешаешь/снимаешь дополнительный класс в котором меняешь нужные стили

Comment: Наверное через useState это делается

Answer (score 0):

При нажатии добавляется класс на основной элемент `wrapper` и далее стилями указано, что должно произойти

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

wrapper.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  wrapper.classList.toggle('change')
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.wrapper img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
}

.wrapper.change img:last-child {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://emojio.ru/images/apple-b/1f31a.png" />
  <img src="https://emojio.ru/images/apple-b/1f31d.png" />
</div>
```